# What is the use of passing arguments to MPI_Init?

Tags: c, mpi

As far as I understand the C implementation of `MPI`, the `MPI_Init` function makes no use of arguments `&argc` and `&argv` passed to it. The `mpiexec` or `mpirun` probably runs multiple programs and passes the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` object to each of the processes through some datastream externally (so that each program can extract information like size, rank etc. - Please correct me here).

When I check the argv[ ] strings, it contains only the program path.

So I think that signature of MPI_Init must be `MPI_Init(void)` instead of `MPI_Init(int* argc, char*** argv)`. Is there any reason for passing arguments to MPI_Init? or is it defined this way for future usage if any?

Comment: @JohnZwinck It is not the same question. My question is not about passing pointer or not! I want to understand why are arguments passed at all. The arguments are not used by MPI and argument passed seems trivial and unusable by MPI. As a matter of fact, I passed empty strings to MPI_Init() and the program worked without any problem.

Comment: The documentation I found said passing NULL for both is acceptable too.  I guess they aren't used.  But MPI is a stable standard, can't be changed now.

Comment: Yes, however I have seen all the programs in literature passing `&argc, &argv` to MPI_Init(), which are the arguments passed by `mpiexec` to the program. At first I thought that the rank and size is passed through arguments by `mpiexec` to `MPI_Init`, but printing the arguments showed that the arguments are of no use. So I want to know whether there is a special case when the arguments contain some information for MPI_Init?

Comment: What does the documentation for your particular MPI implementation say?  Why not just pass the args and forget about it?  :)

Comment: :) The documentation talks nothing about the arguments, other than saying "pointer to number of arguments" and "pointer to argument vector"! The reason why I stumbled upon this is, I wanted to set the number of processes run before calling MPI_Init from inside the program... or so I thought is possible. Anyways thanks for the suggestions.